# Rails - Sort Hash of Hashes based on subhash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, hash

I have the following hash:

```
h = { "people"=>
        { "joe"   => { "score" => 3, "favorite_food" => "pizza"}, 
          "marry" => { "score" => 89, "favorite_food" => "ice_cream" }
         }
     }
```

How do I sort this hash based on score (and keep it sorted)?

ie: the result would be:

```
    { "people"=>
        { 
          "marry" => { "score" => 89, "favorite_food" => "ice_cream" }
          "joe"   => { "score" => 3, "favorite_food" => "pizza"}, 
         }
     }
```

Comment: what do you mean sort a hash?

Comment: If you need to sort... maybe you don't need an hash...

Comment: I am getting results from an API that are json... I just JSON.parsed it to make it a hash... should I leave it a string?

Comment: I don't know what you have to display or do with that data, but maybe transforming them into an array is the first thing to do in this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've meant the evaluation order of the hash values, then you have to reconstruct the sub-hash:

```
h[ 'people' ].replace(h[ 'people' ].to_a.sort do |x, y|
   y[1][ 'score' ] <=> x[1][ 'score' ]
end.to_h)
```

for older version of ruby, use `Hash` constructor:

```
h[ 'people' ].replace( Hash[h[ 'people' ].to_a.sort do |x, y|
   y[1][ 'score' ] <=> x[1][ 'score' ]
end] )
```

**Additional note**: the ordered hash is appeared from ruby version 2.1 (as far as I remember).

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for #<Array:0x0000000a8445e0>  but this does help though... just create a new hash with it sorted...

Comment: @Jeff which version of ruby have you?

Comment: Ruby 2.0... the second one works... I was looking at this as well,

h.deep_symbolize_keys

h.sort_by

Comment: After a "deep symbolize" can you use the sort_by? http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

Comment: @Jeff usage of `#deep_symbolize_keys` throws the NoMethod excpetion

Comment: I think it's rails specific.

Comment: @Jeff yes. try after applying the `#deep_symbolize_keys` use just `#sort`

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer more self-explanatory (and longer) code, you can transform your hash of hashes (let's call it `h`) to an array of hashes (let's call it `a`) that contains all the elements you want to sort but slightly different and then perform the sorting on this array's elements - using whichever key you prefer:

```
a = []
p["people"].each do |p| 
  a << { :name => p, :score => p["score"], :food => p["food"] } 
end

sorted = a.sort_by { |e| e[:score] }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for completion, here is another way to sort it:

```
h.deep_symbolize_keys!
h[:people].sort_by {|k,v| v[:score]}.reverse!
```

I can't speak toward the efficiency of this, but it works.